# What is SendID in email

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am extracting the Journey Builder ( Email) [image] data using the Data Extract Activity.
While the configuration of the Extract Activity it is asking for the

1. Email Send Definition External Key
2. Send IDs

Where I can find these details?
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Email Send Definition External key is the Customer/External key of the User-Initiated Send Definition found in your Automation Studio Activities.

[image: Activities]

[image: Customer/External Key]

Send IDs are JobIDs, which you can find in Email Studio -> Tracking.

[image: SendIDs]

Comment: Hello, @Adam Thank you very much for this information.
I am exporting the emails tracking which I used in the journey.
Now when I am opening that email in the tracking section it is not showing me job Id it is showing me the External Key.
For Rest of the emails which is not part of the journey that is showing the job Ids.
The external key is similar to the job id?

Comment: No, I'd recommend _not_ tracking Journey emails by JobID.  Since they're created behind the scenes as Triggered Sends, the JobIDs change with each version or update.  It's easier to use the [System Data Views](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5) to in Query Activities build Journey email reports.  You can match the Journey Email Customer/External key with the `TriggeredSendCustomerKey in the `_Sent` data view.

Comment: JobID and SubscriberID relate all of the System Data Views together.

Comment: Hey @Adam
Thank you very much for this help.
I am following the below article to help this I am very near to the solution only having problem with send id.
Please note I have only one version of the journey which is running, there is no new and updated version of the that journey

Comment: Hey @Adam
Thank you very much for this help.
I am following the below article to help this I am very near to the solution only having problem with send id.
Please note I have only one version of the journey which is running; there is no new and updated version of the trip.
Please help me to find the Job-id of the email which I am using in the journey.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313980&type=1&mode=1

Comment: JobID and SendID are the same, so you can find that in Email Studio under Tracking -> Sends.

Comment: Hello @Adam
I am not able to find the Jobid and Sendid for the emails which I am using in the journey builder it is just showing me the External key.

Comment: Tracking > Journey Builder Sends should list the JobIDs: https://i.imgur.com/Lukrkdl.png

Comment: I saw for your tracking it is showing the job id but when I am doing the same it is showing me the name and external key instead of job id. :(

Comment: Hello @Adam 
I am able to see job Id for all email except the emails which I am using with journey builder. please see an attcahed shot - https://imgur.com/a/m8xQsLX

Comment: Hello @Adam. When I query the TriggeredSendCustomerKey it still looks like it is a number (Key) that changes when you do an update or create a new version of a journey. Is that correct?

Comment: Customer/external key shouldn't change when you do a new journey version, no.  It would if you swap out the email.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer @Adam